# Changing a variable's value through the stack

Tags: c, stack

Okay we are given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "callstack.h"
#include "tweetIt.h"
#include "badguy2.c"

static char *correctPassword = "ceriaslyserious";
char *message = NULL;

int validateSanity(char *password) {
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(password);i++)
        if(!isalpha(password[i]))
            return 0;
    unsigned int magic = 0x12345678;
    return badguy(password);
}

int validate(char *password) {
    printf("--Validating something\n", password);
    if (strlen(password) > 128) return 0;

    char *passwordCopy = malloc(strlen(password) + 1);
    strcpy(passwordCopy, password);
    return validateSanity(passwordCopy);
}

int check(char *password, char *expectedPassword) {
    return (strcmp(password, expectedPassword) == 0);
}

int main() {
    char *password = "wrongpassword";
    unsigned int magic = 0xABCDE;
    char *expectedPassword = correctPassword;
    if (!validate(password)) {
        printf("--Invalid password!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (check(password, expectedPassword)) {
        if (message == NULL) {
            printf("--No message!\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            tweetIt(message, strlen(message));
            printf("--Message sent.\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("--Incorrect password!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We are supposed to trick `main` into sending a tweet using the function `badguy`. In badguy we have an offset from a previous problem which is the difference between the declaration of `password` in `main` and the argument passed to `badguy`. We have been instructed to use this offset to find the addresses of the `correctPassword` and `password` in main and manipulate the value in `password` to `correctPassword` so when the password check occurs, it is believed to be legitimate. I am having some trouble figuring out how to use this offset to find the addresses and continuing from there.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack Maybe checking out the structure of call stack may help. :)
The information are all on the call stack, so just find the correct offset and you may get the information you want.

Comment: Wouldn't getting the value for the original `password` in main just be subtracting my offset from `badguy` password? This doesn't seem to provide the correct result, although it makes sense to me logically.

Comment: No, you shouldn't, voting is anonymous and commenting on downvotes on questions is considered noise.  Please refrain from doing so in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have good control over your compiler behavior. That is: make sure you know the calling conventions *and* that they're being respected (not optimized away or altered in any manner). This usually boils down to turn off optimization settings, at least for testing under more controlled conditions until a robust method is devised. Pay special attention to variables such as `expectedPassword`, since it is highly likely they'll be optimized away (`expectedPassword` might never be created in the stack, being substituted with the equivalent of `correctPassword`, rendering you with *no* stack reference to the correct password at all).

Secondly, note that `"wrongpassword"` is shorter than `"ceriaslyserious"`; in other words, if I got it straight, attempting to crack into the buffer pointed to by `passwordCopy` (whose size is the length of `"wrongpassword"` plus one) in order to copy `"ceriaslyserious"` into there could result in a segmentation violation. Nonetheless, it should be relatively simple to track the address of `expectedPassword` in the call stack, *if it exists* (see above), specially if you do have already an offset from `main()`'s stack frame.

Considering an x86 32-bit target under controlled circumstances, `expectedPassword` will reside 8 bytes below `password` (4 for `password`, 4 for `magic` if it is not optimized away). Having an offset from `password` to a parameter as you said, it should suffice to subtract the offset from the address of that parameter, and then add 8. The resulting pointer should be `expectedPassword`, which then points to the static area containing the password. Again, double check your environment. Check [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/) for an explanation on the stack layout in x64 (the layout in the 32-bit case is similar).

Lastly, if `expectedPassword` does not exist in the call stack, then, since `correctPassword` is a global static, it will reside in a data segment, rendering the method useless. To achieve the goal in this situation, you would need to carefully scan the data segment with a more intelligent algorithm. It would probably be easier, though, to simply attempt to find the test for `check()`'s return value in the program text and replace with `nop`s (after properly manipulating the page permissions to allow writing to the text segment).

If you're having problems, inspecting the resulting assembly code is the way to go. If you're using GCC, `gcc -S` halts the compilation just before assembling (that is, producing an assembly source code file as output). `objdump -d` could also help. `gdb` can step between instructions, show the disassembly of a frame and display register contents; check the documentation.

These exercises are specially useful to understand how security breaches occur in common programs, and to provide some basic notions on defensive programming.

Comment: Under what optimization settings will the compiler not create reference of the parameters? If it is not stored in the stack, where is it stored?

Comment: This is compiler dependent. Usually, if the variable is small enough to fit a register, and there are registers left for use, the variable is stored on a register. If the variable is used just as a constant l-value, most likely the constant will be used directly (the same effect as a macro). In GCC, as far as I know, _none_ of these optimizations occur if compiled with `-O0`.